# Icons on the "updates" email have inconsistent sizes

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

As per the title:

[image]

Icons on the "updates" email have inconsistent sizes.

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in the next production build.

Comment: Still broken 21 hours later, time to check again?

Comment: @Sklivvz i think it's cached. I updated the [apple touch icon](http://cdn.sstatic.net/skepticsmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png)(which is used for emails) over the weekend and it's on live server already.

Comment: I checked this again for some reason the original fix didn't make it in. Sorry about that. This will be in the next product build, for real!